# template parameter type deduction in user defined conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-conversion, type-deduction

I'm trying to create a `struct timeout`. I would like to use it directly.e.g. `std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout)`. However my user defined conversion fails when converting from `struct timeout`to `std::chrono::duration<rep,period>` for some reason I can't understand.
Here's full code sample:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
template <typename Duration = std::chrono::milliseconds>
struct timeout_tp
{
   using Duration_   = Duration;
   using rep_        = typename Duration_::rep;
   using period_     = typename Duration_::period;

   timeout_tp(const rep_ &timeout) : timeout{timeout} {}    
   operator Duration_() const {return timeout;}
   Duration_ operator()() const {return timeout;}
   //...
   private:   
   Duration_ timeout;
};

int main()
{
   timeout_tp<std::chrono::seconds> timeout{1};
   std::chrono::seconds x = timeout; //OK: struct timeout conversion to std::chrono::seconds.
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(x);
   //std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout); : FAILS!!! Can't understand why... 
   std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout()); //OK : struct timeout operator() returns std::chrono::seconds.
   return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

What do I need to do in order to use the desired syntax?

Error messages issued by the compiler:

main.cpp:38:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘sleep_for(timeout_tp<>&)’
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout); //FAILS!!! Can't understand why...
                                       ^

In file included from main.cpp:16:0:
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:361:7: note: candidate: template void std::this_thread::sleep_for(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>&)
       sleep_for(const chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>& __rtime)
       ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/thread:361:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

main.cpp:38:39: note:   ‘timeout_tp<>’ is not derived from ‘const std::chrono::duration<_Rep1, _Period1>’
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout); //FAILS!!! Can't understand why...

Comment: "Here's full code sample" where are `#include`s?

Comment: @Swordfish They surely wouldn't help with understanding the question.

Comment: @Swordfish Sorry..I've updated.

Comment: @Zereges It would help with me being too lacy to add them.

Answer (score 2):

`::std::this_thread::sleep_for` is a template declared as

```
template< class Rep, class Period >
void sleep_for( const std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period> & sleep_duration );
```

When you pass an instance of `timeout_tp` template parameters `Rep` and `Period` can not be deduced and user-defined conversion operator `timeout_tp` to `std::chrono::milliseconds` is not even taken into consideration.

Comment: I understand that. But what do I need to do to use a syntax like `std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeout)`? How can I "tell" to the compiler that I wish to convert `struct timeout` to `std::chrono::duration<rep,period>'?

Comment: @JacintoResende You can cast it explicitly `std::this_thread::sleep_for(static_cast<timeout_tp::Duration_>(timeout))` or specify template parameters explicitly `std::this_thread::sleep_for<timeout_tp::rep_, timeout_tp::period_>(timeout)`. Or you can just write your own `sleep_for` function that would take `timeout_tp` for convenience.